# How does pandas perform rolling windows internally?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've implemented some feature which behaves like rolling (with some meaningful differences) but I want to improve it's performance.

My question is, lets say I have this array

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When I execute rolling sum of two elements, does pandas generate first this matrix

```
a = [[NaN, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

and then aggregate by rows?

Does it use single for cycles to generate these windows?

I'd like to know how it's rolling system works because It would really help me to improve the performance of some implementations I've got.

Comment: The source code of pandas is available. Why don't you check it?

Comment: I checked it and I think it works like this because I got here. But I'm stuck at the function _convert_frec which I think is the one who makes the resampling step. Then I followed the self._selected_obj prop which belongs to the SelectionMixing class and I couldnt figure out how this is done.
Besides, if it works as I think, it's really increasing memory consumption because generating a matrix would multiply the size of the series while it's processed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link when I wrote "I got here".

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/window.py